# How to install DDR3L RAM into HP ProBook 470 G3?

Tags: memory, installation

I have a HP ProBook 470 G3 [Z4P30PA].

I purchased an extra 8GB or RAM at the same time.  The RAM is HP 8GB DDR3L-1600 1.35V SODIMM [ H6Y77AA ].  This was listed under "accessories" when I made the purchase, so you would presume it's compatible.

I can't figure out how to physically install the RAM.  If you look at the picture, the notch appears to be in the incorrect place.

I have a feeling I need DD4 SODIMM, rather than DDR3L.  I checked back with HP support and they are adamant this is the correct RAM.

Is it possible to install this RAM into this machine?[image: picture of RAM and socket with notch not lining up]

This picture shows the uninstalled RAM in the foreground, with the socket above it.  Further above that is installed RAM which is DDR4.

Comment: @Ramhound [Here](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-probook-470-g3-notebook-pc---customizable-v5c71av-mb) it is mentioned as DD4. Which one is correct.

Comment: @WW. [HP ProBook 470 G3 Notebook PC](http://h20386.www2.hp.com/AustraliaStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=Z4P30PA&opt=&sel=NTB) - Very helpful in the future if you provide the specification page in future questions like this to the product.  There are about 10 different HP ProBook 470 G3 models.  You purchased incompatible memory.  You should return it and purchase DDR4L memory instead.

Comment: Remove the existing ram and compare the new one and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to HP's [website](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-probook-470-g3-notebook-pc---customizable-v5c71av-mb) your laptop takes DDR4

In your picture the installed RAM is DDR4 SODIMM 260-Pin ([PN 820570-001](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01E8M5J4W) that you can barely see on the sticker in your pic)

The one that they sold you that you're trying to install is DDR3 SODIMM 202-Pin ([PN 693374-005](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BK3884K))

The RAM that you are trying to install is not compatible with your laptop.

Comment: When i searched for, HP ProBook 470 G3, I find [this](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/laptops/product-detail.html?oid=7834620#!tab=models) product page indicates DDR3.  The [product page](http://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-probook-470-g3-notebook-pc---customizable-v5c71av-mb) the author provided indicates DDR4.  I had to search for [Z4P30PA](http://h20386.www2.hp.com/AustraliaStore/Merch/Product.aspx?id=Z4P30PA&opt=&sel=NTB) to verify that it is indeed DDR4

Comment: Thanks all. The correct DDR4 RAM arrived and was straightforward to install.

Answer (score 0):

Insert as shown on picture, then push down until the metal locks click into place.
[image]

Comment: Will this work given the notches don't align?

Comment: No, as @n8te posted, your RAM are not the correct type and therefore not compatible with the laptop.